# How is the protest against Elsevier coming along?

Tags: ethics, publishers, elsevier

I reread Tim Gowers protest against Elsevier as well as other writings from well-known professors that indicate they still protest.

I'm also aware of the boycott.

Has this protest actually changed Elsevier's business practices?

Comment: Have you read the article on the boycott on Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Cost_of_Knowledge

Comment: @allure thanks, I've updated my question to clarify this.

Comment: Does the section "reaction from Elsevier" answer your question? If not, what is missing?

Comment: @allure I just really want a Winter Bash hat, to be honest.